# LuaJava and Latest LuaBinaries

Tags: java, lua, binaries, luajava

Does anyone know if LuaJava works out of the box with the latest LuaBinaries or just the 5.1.1 binaries? Thanks.

http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problems using it with Lua 5.1.4:

Output:

```
C:\luajava>lua -v
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

C:\luajava>java -cp "luajava-1.1.jar" org.keplerproject.luajava.Console
API Lua Java - console mode.
> example = 10
> example = example + 20
> print(example)
30
```

I am using Lua on Windows

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped! Any chance of marking this answer as correct (the tick to the left of it)?